# Mutating array of objects into array of chunked arrays containing objects with common property

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects that all contain a property `snail`.

I'd like to mutate this array into an array of arrays, with each element array containing objects *that have a common property `snail`*

It is very similar to lodash _.partition, except it needs to happen an indeterminate number of times, recursively, and be on a flat level and not deeply nested.

Thank you for any guidance.

Here is a sample data structure: `[ { hi: "bungalo" }, { hi: 'bodego' }, { hi: 'bodego' }, { hi: 'pet rock' } ]`

`[ [ { snail: 'big' }, { snail: 'big' } ], [ {snail: 'small' }, {snail: 'small'} ] ]`

Comment: Ah it helps to write it out sometimes - I could use _.flatten to solve the problem of nesting. But I still need to write my first recursive function!

Comment: It would be useful to post a sample of the data structure, it's pretty vague as it stands.

Comment: Its super simple. `[ { hi: "bungalo" }, { hi: 'bodego' }, { hi: 'bodego' }, { hi: 'pet rock' } ] `

Comment: Question not clear... what do you expect as output? And why do you __need__ to mutate?

Comment: Agreed, how does "recursively" fit in here? Will the array be sorted?

Comment: with respect to the sample data structure can you also post the sample output expected? I am still confused about your question.

Comment: If you say so. An array containing element arrays that contain objects with common property snail - now in question above

Comment: Got to be done for nested ng-repeats in angular.

Comment: Wasn't sure if recursion was required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played a little bit and created the following snippet which does what you're looking for in two different ways, the second one being more elegant I think:

```
var data = [ { snail: "bungalo", i: 1 }, { snail: 'bodego', i: 2 }, { snail: 'bodego', i: 3 }, { snail: 'pet rock', i: 4 }, { snail: "bungalo", i: 5 } ];

var multiPartitioned = _(data).uniq('snail').pluck('snail').map(function(snail) {
  return _.filter(data, 'snail', snail);
}).value();

var multiPartitionedMoreElegant = _(data).groupBy('snail').values().value();

console.log(multiPartitioned);
console.log(multiPartitionedMoreElegant);
```

You can see this example on CodePen:
http://codepen.io/NicBright/pen/VeWXpj?editors=001

Regards,
Nicolas

Comment: ah, group by! that did it. I didn't think I needed recursion at first, but didn't see this group by. Obviously need to get more familiar with lodash chaining & .value().

Answer (score 1):

What about the dead simple:

```
bysnail = {};
objects.forEach(function(x){
    (bysnail[x.snail] || (bysnail[x.snail] = [])).push(x);
});
```

?

The output is an object mapping `snail` values to the list of objects with that value.

Comment: That works, except for this application I need an array inside an array for the ordering in ng-repeats